# jquery datepicker: set default date based on first date selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two date inputs and the second date needs to be after the first. I would therefore like the second input's datepicker to open up having the first date chosen. This is the "defaultDate" option, except it needs to be dynamic.

Edit:

So far I just initiate then the usual way:

```
$(function() {$( "#from_date" ).datepicker();  }); 
$(function() {$( "#to_date" ).datepicker();  });
```

Comment: Give the code you tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$( "#from_date" ).datepicker({
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#to_date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
  }
});
$( "#to_date" ).datepicker({
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#from_date" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, that's awesome! (I only need the from_date onClose function, but cool to show it the other way, too.)